# Dependencies when moved from sub-module to parent module are not getting resolved

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a parent module A that has 2 submodules B and C within it. 
Both the submodules have the same dependencies listed in them. So I removed the dependencies from both and put them in the parent module. 
But getting compilation errors in building all 3 modules as classes coming out of those dependencies are not getting resolved.

Parent maven project A has B and C defined in the `<modules>` tag.
Both B and C have A listed in the `<parent>` tag.
Dependencies from B and C removed and put in A's pom.

Expected result - Build Success

Actual result - Compilation error

Comment: The parent module is the parent POM of both A and B?

Comment: Yes it is. On clicking the <parent> tag, I am getting redirected to the pom of parent module.

Comment: You did not accidentally put the dependencies into `<dependencyManagement>`?